# CSS gurus: font shorthand and CSS duplication

Tags: font-size, css

This is more of a general best practice question rather than a very focused one.
I'm a big fan of the font shorthand as it solves most of the line-height headaches I had when I was using just font-family, font-size etc etc and it really cuts down on the total number of the CSS declarations while providing full control on the typography.

The problem is, as font-sizes change throught a page, so do the line-heights, so I'm finding myself redefining font several times, like so:

```css
.lastUnit h2 {font:normal 23px/23px Calibri,Tahoma,sans-serif;color:#a51d21;padding: 21px 0 15px 70px;}
.lastUnit a:link, .lastUnit a:visited {color:#a57129;font:normal 16px/16px Calibri,Tahoma,sans-serif;}
h1 {font: normal 26px/26px Calibri,Tahoma,sans-serif;border-bottom:2px dotted #bababa;color:#204fe7;padding-bottom: 8px;margin-bottom: 8px;}
h2 {font: normal 22px/22px Calibri,Tahoma,sans-serif;color: #a41d21;margin-bottom:12px;padding-bottom: 12px;}
.internal h2 {border-bottom: 2px dotted #62c6c7;}h2.section {font:normal 20px/16px Calibri,Tahoma,sans-serif;color:#1d7373;border:0;margin: 0 0 15px 0;padding-bottom:12px;border-bottom:2px dotted #62c7c8;clear:both;height:18px;text-transform:uppercase;}
ul,ol,p {font:normal 16px/24px Calibri,Tahoma,serif;}
h3 {font: normal 18px/18px Calibri,Tahoma,sans-serif;color:#204fe7;margin:6px 0;}
```

I have a strong feeling this code is not optimized... I'm thinking to declare the font-family on my body (or on an id very high in the markup) so I don't have to repeat it each time, but then I'll have to use font-family, line-height and some times font-weight.. Which makes for pretty much the same amount of CSS.

Any ideas or tips to optimise this procedure? Maybe additional classes in the markup?

ps: for Stackoverflow admins: That would be a question for "coding style" tag but it's not allowed to use it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to write CSS as if I were designing a database or defining OO-classes. I would:

1. try to eliminate redundancy in the CSS
2. define generic CSS rules first and then the specific cases
3. avoid shorthands if necessary

Here is an example:

```
h1, h2, h3 {
    font: normal large/1em Calibri,Tahoma,sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, the problem is that 26px needs different line-height than 18px.. So we'd need to add line-height declaration..

Comment: The `1em` implies that the line height matches the corresponding heading's font size. But yes, you will need extra CSS rules depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Start from this:

```
body { font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; }
* { line-height: 1.3; }
```

Then define `h1`, `h2` etc. sizes in percentages. Then set colors, and so on. To tune spacing between blocks (e.g. between a heading and a paragraph, or between items of a list), it is almost always better to use vertical margins rather than line height.

There is no need to create a mixed salad of font settings, and the `font` shorthand tends to confuse rather than help.

Calibri is a nice little font, unfortunately with no suitable fallback on systems that lack it—but virtually any sans-serif font is a better fallback than Tahoma, which is completely different from Calibri in almost every way (except being sans-serif).

Comment: Indeed, Calibri sucks, but where I work the designers have no idea about how to make layouts for the web, I got a design with MYRIAD font (the designer just picked what he liked..) so I saw that Calibri ressembles it.. What you suggest as a sans-serif fallback except Tahoma?

Comment: @George Katsanos, I did not write that Calibri sucks, rather the opposite. It is well-designed in a creative way (just with some quirks like horrendous “→” character), and this implies that there is no good backup for it. This is one of the cases where there is probably no better backup than the generic `sans-serif`.

Answer (score 0):

if all share the same font-family, why not declare it in one place at the top, and then define the "fine details". In other words, the best practice is to set the common/general rules and then redefine the ones you need.

example:

```
/* define the font family/general characteristics */

h1, h2, h3 {
    font:normal 23px/23px Calibri,Tahoma,sans-serif;
}

/* define the details for the ones you would like */
h1 {
    font-size:26px;
    line-height:26px;
    border-bottom:2px dotted #bababa;
    color:#204fe7;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Comment: I guess that's one way to go, but the strings     font-size:26px;    line-height:26px;
are more or less equal to 

    font:normal 26px/26px Calibri,Tahoma,sans-serif;
in terms of character length..

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos yes, but it makes no sence to write the full shorthand if you just need to change the line-height, that will take you longer and it's harder (and it's bad coding) if for instance you need to change the font, or any other rule in that shorthand.

Comment: Indeed, I think I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to shorten this down would be to specify one tag that sets the font family. A bit like this

```
body {
  font-family:Calibri,Tahoma,sans-serif;
}
```

Then you can fine tune each element further down your css styles.

Also just to mention. CSS doesn't cause that much of an issue when loading the page. I would focus more on optimizing images and any server side code.